# Sqlite result set contain a null value

Tags: ios, sqlite

I get a result set from sqlite which looks something like this:

Null, 23, 34, 45  (being (say) 4 items returned)

The null value is correct - however when I try to add it to an array in objective-c with the following code I get an error - Null cstring - here's my code:

**[array addObject:[NSString stringWithUTF8String:(char *)sqlite3_column_text(statement, 0)]];**

I tried unsuccessfully testing for the null before adding it to the array and replacing it with a zero but so far no luck.

Could someone please help me to handle the null value so I can add maybe a zero into the array.

Thanks for any help.

Comment: You can't add a `nil` to an NSMutableArray.  You will get a nasty exception if you try.  You can, of course, add a zero-length NSString, or an NSNull object.

Comment: Thanks for that - but what would be the best way to test for the existence of the null value - before I try to add it to the array.

Comment: `if (value == null)`.  Do this *before* doing stringWithUTF8String.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As Hot Licks said, check the return value and either add a string created from that, or add `[NSNull null]`.

```
const unsigned char *column0 = sqlite3_column_text(statement, 0);
if (column0)
    [array addObject:[NSString stringWithUTF8String:(const char *)column0]];
else
    [array addObject:[NSNull null]];
```

Answer (score 1):

Handling null as suggested is a good option.

You can also modify queries to force column to always be `TEXT` using `CAST(column_name AS TEXT)`, or force NULLs to empty strings using `COALESCE(column_name, '')`.